# SQL Server IDENTITY(1,1) Column not generated in sync with UpdatedDate

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a strange situation in my SQL Server based application and I'm trying to figure out what I'm missing in attempting to explain it.

I have a trigger on a table and every time a record is updated/deleted in table the trigger inserts a log into a log table. Bellow is an example of my log table with something I discovered recently.

```
ID    UpdatedDate
------------------------------
10    2018-07-06 12:20:54.287
11    2018-07-06 12:20:54.657
12    2018-07-06 12:20:54.703
13    2018-07-06 12:20:54.910
14    2018-07-06 12:20:54.900
15    2018-07-06 12:20:54.953
16    2018-07-06 12:20:55.070
17    2018-07-06 12:20:55.087
18    2018-07-06 12:20:55.100
19    2018-07-06 12:20:55.113
20    2018-07-06 12:20:55.117
21    2018-07-06 12:20:55.143
22    2018-07-06 12:20:55.243
23    2018-07-06 12:20:53.973
```

If you look at the very last record #23, the `UpdateDate` is less than the `UpdatedDate` of the other (older) records with smaller IDs. This is strange to me because the ID column is defined with `IDENTITY(1,1)` meaning it's monotonically increasing. So the higher the value of ID the newer the record thus the `UpdatedDate` column should always be increasing, and the record #23 should NOT have an older timestamp.

BTW the insert into the log table just uses `GETDATE()` for the `UpdatedDate` column.

Can this be explained somehow?

Comment: Edit your question and show the (relevant) code for the trigger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you are measuring two different things.  The `updatedDate` is probably more like when the trigger is called -- or even when the `update`/`delete` is called.  The `id` is when the row is actually inserted into the table.

So, what you are seeing is that an older update/delete is getting to the log at a later time.  I speculate that this is because the process takes longer -- common culprits would be more rows being affected, page splits, index updates, triggers.  Because it takes longer, the older date is being logged later than other transactions.

I think if you used a `default getdate()` for the column, you would see more consistency.

Comment: So what you're saying is that it might be a race condition on the trigger. The last record #23 takes a longer time to process but since it's using the GETDATE() function explicitly the date has already been captured. So if other trigger executions complete before it does, the ID will have been incremented and but the date is the captured date from when the trigger execution started. I think that makes sense... Wondering if using the default getdate() on table definition will just improve consistency or will guarantee it?

Comment: @DKhanaf . . . You actually summarized that very well.  I don't know the internals well enough to know when the default value is added under such race conditions.